# VSCODE intellisense stopped working all of a sudden MAC

Tags: visual-studio-code

This morning, I was able to view vscode intellisense suggestions with PIXI.js.

My index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Fun with PIXI</title>

  <script src="node_modules/pixi.js/dist/pixi.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My index.js:

```
const app = new PIXI.Application();

document.body.appendChild(app.view);
```

Serving the file and running index.js is fine. I am just so annoyed that I lost intellisense suggestions for PIXI.js (or any third party libraries). I still do see Intellisense suggestions working for DOM APIs (i.e. document methods, etc...)

[image]

Comment: Does this still happen if you disable all extensions and restart VS Code?

Comment: Yes, I even did a fresh install of VSCODE, and removed all locally cached files related to VSCODE on my mac...